# Why does a failed filename generation make zsh stop processing a script?

Tags: zsh

I was trying to write a short script which would write all the executable programs found in `$PATH`:

```
for dir in $(tr ':' ' ' <<<"${PATH}"); do
  for pgm in $dir/*; do
    if command -v "${pgm}" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
      echo "${pgm}"
    fi
  done
done | sort >file
```

In bash, it works as expected, but zsh stops processing the script as soon as a filename generation fails in the inner loop:

```
for pgm in $dir/*; do
           ^^^^^^
  ...
done
```

As a result, since my `$PATH` contains a directory which doesn't contain any file (`/usr/local/sbin`), in zsh, the script fails to write the executables found in the directories afterwards.

Here's another code showing the same issue:

```
for f in /not_a_dir/*; do
  echo 'in the loop'
done
echo 'after the loop'
```

In bash, this command outputs:

```
in the loop
after the loop
```

And exits with the code `0`.

While in zsh, the same command outputs:

```
no matches found: /not_a_dir/*
```

And exits with the code `1`.

The difference of behavior between the shells seems to come from the `nomatch` option, which is described in `man zshoptions`:

> NOMATCH (+3) <C> <Z>
>
> If a pattern for filename generation has no matches, print an error, instead of leaving  it  unchanged
>   in the argument list.  This also applies to file expansion of an initial `~` or `=`.

And also explained in `man zshexpn` (section FILENAME GENERATION):

> The word is replaced with a list of sorted filenames that match the pattern.  If no matching pattern is found, the shell gives an error message, unless the NULL_GLOB option is set, in which case the word is deleted; or unless the NOMATCH option is unset, in which case the word is left unchanged.

Because if I unset `nomatch`, zsh behaves like bash:

```
unsetopt nomatch
for f in /not_a_dir/*; do
  echo 'in the loop'
done
echo 'after the loop'
```

Now I understand the difference of behaviors between bash and zsh, and why the script raises an error in zsh, but I want to understand why a failed filename generation makes zsh immediately stop processing a script.
So, I tried to reproduce the same issue by replacing the failed filename generation with a failed command (by executing `not_a_cmd`):

```
for f in ~/*; do
  not_a_cmd
done
echo 'after the loop'
```

But the output of this script is almost identical in both shells (apart from the error messages due to `not_a_cmd`). In particular, both shells print:

```
after the loop
```

And both shells exit with the code `0`.

Why does a failed filename generation (like `for f in /not_a_dir/*`) make zsh stop processing a script, but not a failed command (like `not_a_cmd`)?

I'm using `zsh 5.6.2-dev-0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`.

Comment: This is a genuine question -- why `printf "shopt -s failglob \n echo *.foo \n echo afterwards" | bash` will print "afterwards", but  `printf "echo *.foo \n echo afterwards" | zsh` and `bash -c 'shopt -s failglob; echo *.foo; echo afterwards'` won't? I'm too lazy to search if this has been discussed to depth on this site -- but please change the title of your question; it's begging for kneejerk deletion; there are a hundred thousands cases where zsh may stop processing a script ;-)

Comment: @mosvy I don't know the answer, but in your first command, if I replace the second newline with a semicolon, `afterwards` is not printed. Out of the 3 bash commands (the two you provided plus the one I just mentioned), two fail to print `afterwards`. I'm not sure, but it makes me think that the one which does print `afterwards` is the exception: `printf "shopt -s failglob \n echo *.foo \n echo afterwards" | bash`. For some reason, the second newline is able to prevent bash from interrupting the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a feature, not a bug.

As it says in [Zsh's manual, section "Errors"](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Grammar.html#Errors):

> Certain errors are treated as fatal by the shell: in an interactive shell, they cause control to return to the command line, and in a non-interactive shell they cause the shell to be aborted. […]
>
> Fatal errors found in non-interactive shells include:
>
> - […]
> - File generation errors where not caught by the option [`BAD_PATTERN`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-BADPATTERN)
> - […]
> - File generation failures where not caused by [`NO_MATCH`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-NOMATCH) or similar options.

As for the reasoning behind it, I found this [email exchange in the Zsh mailing list archives](http://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2005/msg00301.html):

> > In other shells this is implemented in a very
> > simple way, if the wildcard can be expanded, then it is expanded,
> > otherwise an asterisk is sent as an argument to the application.
>
> Yes, other shells do it that way, but that has its downsides.  For
> instance, if you run "touch *,c" it's better to get "no match" rather
> than creating a useless *,c file.  Or if you type a command like this:
> "rsync -avP *.html *.shmtl *.php host:/dest/" (note the misspelling),
> it is better to get a "no match" error right away than to get a single
> open-error embedded in all the output that you then have to figure out
> at the end of the transfer.  I much prefer to simply put single quotes
> around any wild-carded file names that should not be expanded rather
> than to configure the shell to include a wildcard that didn't match
> anything.  YMMV, of course, but if you give it a try, you may find
> that you come to prefer it as well.